# How to add nuget packages to shared project

Tags: c#

I created shared project on visual studio and I'm like to make UWP, WINPHONE, Xamarin using MVVMCross.
But seems can't add Nuget package to shared project. I'm not sure, If I'd like to make ViewModel in shared project, I need to include MVVMCross sdk in the project.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared project doesn't need to have any references/packages. You can try to install that packages to both each projects.

Comment: Do you implemented MVVMCross to this project?

Comment: @Allu the question is, do all those platforms support MVVMCross? If not you may need to install them on the ones that support the package.

Comment: Yeah, It used MVVMCross

Comment: Yes, MVVM must support all platforms

Comment: Hi Meteoric, I checked your project, It's good to understand shared project. Thanks.

Comment: @Meteoric - your link is 404. Can you elaborate in your answer what the solution is? I.e. if I want to use lib "Abc" in my shared project, how can I edit my Shared Project to reference "Abc"?